# Simple sum function test not working in jest

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

`q.js` : - /src/q.js

```js
function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

module.exports = sum;
```

`q.test.js` : - /tests/q.test.js

```js
const sum = require('../src/q');

test('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', () => {
  const result = sum(1, 3);
  expect(result).toBe(4);
});
```

Even this gives an error, this is exactly copied from the `jest` documentation! 
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started

**error screenshot**:

[image: error screenshot]

Comment: Did You check if const sum = require('../src/q'); gives sothing other than nothing.
I think const sum = require('./src/q'); will work better

Comment: I agree with @nbk, try to debug the code and see what resides in the `sum` variable. Probably issues with import/exports

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: try `require('../src/q.js')`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need to use CommonJS module instead of ES6 module?

Why dont't you try:

`export default sum`
and then
`import sum from './path/to/sum'`
?